# How set metric system default and unchangeable in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I just moved to the US and suddenly every search on google maps uses miles as the default option. I can go to options and change it to Km for every search but I was looking for something permanent. 
The language setting of my google account is Spanish and when I search "The weather" on google, it gives me back information in Spanish with temperatures in °C and winds in Km/h.

I tried some proposed solutions like using maps.google.es but it doesn't work.
I was able to set this up on my phone but I can't find the solution for the computer maps.google.com

I'm using windows 10 setted in ENG (US) with a LAA keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, we don't deal with specific web sites/apps here, but you may be able to get help at the Web Apps Stack Exchange site.

Comment: If you moved to the US, the way to assimilate is to immerse yourself.  Get used to using real units of measure instead of that strange metric stuff the rest of the world uses.  :-)